# Registering a Jackson module for Spring Data REST

Tags: jackson, spring-data-rest

I have a working project based on the Spring Data REST [example project](https://github.com/springsource/spring-data-rest-webmvc), and I'm trying to do custom serialization using a [Jackson module](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules) based on this [wiki page](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/wiki/Adding-custom-%28de%29serializers-to-Jackson%27s-ObjectMapper).

Here's my Jackson module:

```
public class CustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomModule.class);

    public CustomModule() {
        super("CustomModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        logger.debug("CustomModule.setupModule");
        SimpleSerializers simpleSerializers = new SimpleSerializers();
        simpleSerializers.addSerializer(new CustomDateTimeSerializer());
        context.addSerializers(simpleSerializers);
    }

}
```

The [wiki page](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/wiki/Adding-custom-%28de%29serializers-to-Jackson%27s-ObjectMapper) says:

> Any Module bean declared within the scope of your ApplicationContext will be picked up by the exporter and registered with its ObjectMapper.

I'm still pretty new to Spring, so I might just be putting my module bean definition in the wrong place; currently it's in `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-data-rest/shared.xml`, which is imported from `repositories-export.xml`:

```
<bean id="customModule" class="org.hierax.wpa.schema.mapping.CustomModule" />
```

I don't see the log statement in `setupModule`, but I do see log output for other classes in the same package.

I'm using Spring Data REST 1.0.0.RC2.

Comment: No, but I've asked on the Spring Data forum, and maybe it'll get a reply there: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130782-Spring-Data-REST-registering-a-Jackson-module-for-serialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had success using the solution outlined in the wiki entry that you have linked to (although perhaps it has changed since this stack overflow post)

In my instance I was using spring-data-rest-webmvc@1.0.0.RELEASE

Your code seems to be correct and provided that your application context is being loaded correctly I don't see any reason for it not to be working.

I've attached my simpler Module which exemplifies the use of a date formatter:

```
@Component
public class JsonMarshallingConfigModule extends SimpleModule {

  public JsonMarshallingConfigModule() {
    super("JsonMarshallingConfigModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT"));
  }

  @Override public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    context.getSerializationConfig().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"));
  }
}
```

Perhaps it can be used to outline if it is infact the jackson module that is the problem or spring-data-rest-mvcweb.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! I've lately updated to spring-data-rest-webmvc@1.0.0.RELEASE and migrated to code-based configuration as in the example project, and I now have it working with the addition of @Component on the CustomModule.

Comment: Can't seem to make it work. The component is loaded, I can see the instance been created, however, setupModule() is not invoked. Why?

Answer (score 12):

Currently, it's possible to customize a module in Spring Boot like this:

```
@Bean
public Module customModule() {
  return new CustomModule();
}
```

Reference: [Latest Jackson integration improvements in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#with-spring-boot)